# Is it possible to rewrite HOST header in k8s Ingress Controller?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, haproxy, envoyproxy

Due to some legacy application that relies on Host header to function correctly, I need to have an Ingress (proxy, etc) that capable of rewrite Host header and pass that to downstream (backend). Is there any Ingress Controller that supports this functionality?

Example:

End user access our website through `foo.com/a` for backend `a` and `foo.com/b` for backend `b`. But since `a` and `b` are legacy app, it only accept:

- `a` accepts connection when `Host: a.foo.com`
- `b` accepts connection when `Host: b.foo.com`

Answer (score 38):

This can be done using this annotation: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: host.example.com`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether you can find appropriate annotation within [NGINX](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) Ingress Controller for Host header modification to match your requirement as well. However, you can consider using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` [annotation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#configuration-snippet) in order to append configuration snippet to the location block inside `nginx.conf` of the particular Nginx controller pod:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Host www.example-host.com;
  name: my-app
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-app.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
        path: /app
          serviceName: my-app
          servicePort: http
```

We set here Host header `www.example-host.com` for target URL `my-app.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks for that `configuration-snippet` suggestion. Although it still isn't answering my question, your answer is still useful for other similar use cases.

Comment: I get errors about multiple host headers being set when using this. The nginx.conf contains double proxy_set_header Host with this snippet

Comment: This doesn't work. Keycloak throws 400 Bad request after adding this annotation to ingress.

Comment: Do not use this, use the upstream-vhost annotation above.
I lost a lot of time to find out ingress-nginx creates 2 Host headers in this case, which gave an unclear 400 in the upstream server

Answer (score 1):

I want to add my finding to this question of mine.

Although my solution is not using k8s Ingress Controller, our cluster is using Istio and Istio's VirtualService supports rewrite the `uri` and `authority` (Host header) as documented in this link: https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#HTTPRewrite

To know how I implement that in my case, you can take a look at this link: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/11668

Answer (score 0):

you can use ingress nginx controller on Kubernetes and set head and also transfer to backend and manage services connection from ingress objects.

here sharing link for rewrite target from header: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

ingress nginx will be also good with SSL cert manager you can add it.

manage other thing using annotations of ingress.

check this out for ingress SSL setup you can modify it and per your need: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

ingress will be like at last

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myapp.abc.com
    secretName: ingress-tls
  rules:
  - host: myapp.abc.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /my-service
        backend:
          serviceName: my-backend
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Hi @Harsh, sorry but i don't think Nginx Ingress Controller support overwrite the Host header. Can you show the example? AFAIK, it only supports uri path rewrite

Comment: yes it's only support uri path ...you want to write ?

Comment: i think with this annotation you can do it. nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /

Comment: Hi Harsh, I want to rewrite the Host/Authority header.  in vanilla nginx,  it can be done by `proxy_set_header Host <custom-host>;`.

Comment: thankyou so much for sharing i get to know something not used vanilla nginx ..thanks